# SQL - LAG Function - Running Total

Tags: sql, oracle, select, lag

I hope someone can please help. I don't know if this is possible but here goes.

Using SQL Developer connected to an Oracle database.

I have the following Data Set being returned from a query

```
Item  Qty  On Hand
A     6     88
A     6     88
A     6     88
B     2      4
B     1      4
B     2      4
```

Using the LAG function for field Shortage

```
Lag(Qty) Over (Partition By Item Order By Item) As Shortage
```

Returns

```
Item  Qty  On_Hand   Shortage
----  ---  -------   ---------
A     6     88       NULL
A     6     88       6
A     6     88       6
B     2      4       NULL
B     1      4       1
B     2      4       2
```

I Solve the NULL value by using

```
Nvl(Lag(Qty) Over (Partition By Item Order By Item), On_Hand + Qty) As Shortage
```

(If The 'LAG' Value is Null replace the NULL with the Current On_Hand - Qty)

```
Item  Qty  On_Hand   Shortage                                 
A     6     88        82
A     6     88         6
A     6     88         6
B     2      4         2
B     1      4         2
B     2      4         1
```

That is fine for the first row. What I am really looking for is

```
Item  Qty  On_Hand   Shortage  Shortage2
                               (Funtion Below)  
A     6     88        82
A     6     88        76
A     6     88        70
B     2      4         2
B     1      4         1
B     2      4        -1
```

where the Shortage column is effectively a calculation of

The Previous Row Shortage Value - Current Row Quantity Required.

Is this possible ?

I do hope so.

Many thanks in advance to anyone for your assistance

Regards

Iain

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a cumulative sum.  However, you need a column that specifies the ordering of the rows, and no such column is obvious in your data:

```
select t.*,
       (on_hand - sum(qty) over (partition by item order by ?)) as shortage
from t;
```

You can use `item` but the results are not stable -- that is, you can run the same code twice and get different results.

Comment: The Order of the data is currently only by item but I can add a secondary sort that will sort that problem

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I will build this into my query and see how we go. Really appreciate your time and help